# How to make the Featured page excluded from product sorting

Tags: price, filter, position, sort

I have noticed that when you are in any normal product category and use the sort filter, by let's say "price", that filter will remain set in when you move on to other categories.  My issue is that if a customer returns to our Featured products page, that filter is still in place and the products that we want to be shown in a particular order, are no longer in that order.

I am stuck between attempting to get the product sort filter to default back to "position" after the customer changes categories, or perhaps just make it so the featured page is excluded from any previous sort filters put in to place.

We have 30 products on the featured page, with about another 45 that you cannot see.  We have them there just in case something goes out of stock because we do not want the page to look bare.  The top 4 positions are usually "products of the day", which is driving this need to have the featured page remain in position order, regardless of any sorting in other category pages.

Any advice?

Answer (score 0):

Actually magento is  ***save latest selected sort order & sort  direction in Session variable.***

So, whenever customer   move  other category then  magento is *`carried that latest applied sort order & sort  direction value`* at   that session variable and** apply that into  current browse category**.

That why you getting the problem.

If you want to prevent this then you need to customization Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_List_Toolbar